# Spring boot security configuration with both dynamic matchers and roles

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, role-based-access-control

I am looking for a solution where I could use spring boot security to manage user access with specifics from below:

1. Every user is tied to a list of groups.
   **Groups are dynamic**, meaning that a new group can be assigned/removed to/from the user at any point.
2. There are dynamically created entities.
   For example let's think of them as "articles" on some blog website :)
   Similarly like users, those **"articles" are tired to a list of groups** that can access it.

**In summary**: a system where groups and access list are known at runtime.

I do not know much about spring security, so I was looking for some answers on the web, but couldn't find anything. All snippets are based on static antMatchers and roles, like this:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/something_else_instead_of_this").hasRole("ROLE_and_instead_of_this_static_role");
    }

    (...)

}
```

Is there any way of creating your own **custom Authenticator** or something like that, which based on **(1)** URL would find the "article", therefore the groups allowed to access, and **(2)** the user logged, therefore the assigned groups **=>** would determine if I can proceed with processing the request or return 401 immediately ;)

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: did you get the answer of your problem, I am facing the same problem, if you found any solution then please tell me that how I can resolve it

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this solely in the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` but here is a similar set-up that takes advantage of Spring Security and demonstrates how to add the access checks to controller methods.

Additional `pom.xml` dependencies:

```xml
    ...
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    ...
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
      <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    ...
```

(The latter only if you're using Thymeleaf.)

The `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@NoArgsConstructor @Log4j2
public class WebSecurityConfigurerImpl extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Autowired private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**",
                         "/webjars/**", "/webjarsjs");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .and().logout().permitAll();
    }
}
```

In the web MVC `@Controller`, anyone can read an article (whether logged-in or not):

```java
    @RequestMapping(method = { GET }, value = { "/article/{slug}/" })
    @PreAuthorize("permitAll()")
    public String article(Model model, @PathVariable String slug) {
        ...
    }
```

But only AUTHORs may use the preview feature:

```java
    @RequestMapping(method = { GET }, value = { "/preview/" })
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('AUTHOR')")
    public String preview(Model model) {
        ...
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = { POST }, value = { "/preview/" })
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('AUTHOR')")
    public String previewPOST(Model model,
                              Principal principal, HttpSession session,
                              HttpServletRequest request,
                              @Valid PreviewForm form, BindingResult result) {
        ...
    }
```

This is also supported in the Thymeleaf template where the menu is conditionally displayed if the user is an AUTHOR.

```xml
              <li th:ref="navbar-item" sec:authorize="hasAuthority('AUTHOR')">
                <button th:text="'Author'"/>
                <ul th:ref="navbar-dropdown">
                  <li><a th:text="'Preview'" th:href="@{/preview/}"/></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
```

And handling Login/Logout menus to demonstrate other available security predicates:

```xml
              <li th:ref="navbar-item" sec:authorize="!isAuthenticated()">      
                <a th:text="'Login'" th:href="@{/login}"/>                      
              </li>                                                             
              <li th:ref="navbar-item" sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">       
                <button sec:authentication="name"/>                             
                <ul th:ref="navbar-dropdown">                                   
                  <li><a th:text="'Change Password'" th:href="@{/password}"/></\
li>                                                                             
                  <li><a th:text="'Logout'" th:href="@{/logout}"/></li>         
                </ul>                                                           
              </li>
```

(The rest are implementation details that may be helpful for illustration but not necessarily specific to your question.  Specifically, I suggest this is where your logic would be for "dynamic' groups.)

The `UserDetailsService` implementation relies on `JpaRepository` implementations and sets the user's grants:

```java
@Service
@NoArgsConstructor @ToString @Log4j2
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired private CredentialRepository credentialRepository;
    @Autowired private AuthorRepository authorRepository;
    @Autowired private SubscriberRepository subscriberRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = null;
        Optional<Credential> credential =
            credentialRepository.findById(username);

        if (credential.isPresent()) {
            HashSet<GrantedAuthority> set = new HashSet<>();

            subscriberRepository.findById(username)
                .ifPresent(t -> set.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("SUBSCRIBER")));

            authorRepository.findById(username)
                .ifPresent(t -> set.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("AUTHOR")));

            user = new User(username, credential.get().getPassword(), set);
        } else {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
        }

        return user;
    }
}
```

And an example of one of `JpaRepository`:

```java
@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public interface AuthorRepository extends JpaRepository<Author,String> {
    public Optional<Author> findBySlug(String slug);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it cleared some thinks for me. Unfortunately, I this is not the answer I am looking for.  The `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('AUTHOR')")` need to be hardcoded and I want to check if article access group matches to user groups dynamically. Because as I mentioned it all can change at any moment. I guess spring boot security is not the way to go with it :) Probably I will need to intercept the request and write some generic method for that.